# Storyboard UIViewController not appear

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboard

I recently started using storyboard.
I have the main viewcontroller, which by code must call another viewcontroller.

in storyboard, I created a "segue" that goes from the first to the second controller, with the identifier "segueToSignSelection."

in the main viewcontroller, when I need to call up the second viewcontroller, insert this code:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToSignSelection" sender:self];
```

that calls this method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueToSignSelection"])
    {

    signSelectionViewController = (SignSelectionViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];

    [self presentModalViewController:segue.destinationViewController animated:YES];

    [segue.destinationViewController test];

    }
}
```

in the second controller, the test method is invoked. But the view does not appear. What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to present the modal view controller yourself. This is something you declare in segue type in storyboard design. Try to remove that and see if it works.

Comment: don't work. The alert: unused variable signSelectionViewController. The code `SignSelectionViewController *signSelectionViewController = (SignSelectionViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];`

Comment: The alert is normal, because you declare and never use it. Did you check if the segue type in storyboard in interface builder is declared as 'modal' too ? I cannot see anything wrong in prepareForSegue, try to post more code.